# customize glossaries

Tags: styles, latex, glossaries

I am using the glossaries package and wonder if it is possible to customize the appearance of the output. For example I want to make the spaces between the entries smaller or changing the style of the page and line numbers (from 6-20 to 6.20). There is nothing to be found in the manual on such things.

In the header I have:

```
    \usepackage{glossaries}
    \makenoidxglossaries
    \newglossaryentry{entry}{name={entry},description={Bla Bla Bla}}
```

and in the document I  am using:

```
bla bla \edgls{entry} bla bla
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set the appearance via `\setglossarystyle{<style>}` But I would like to change the spacing by hand.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197222/formatting-for-glossaries#197226) on spacing and glossary style and more documentation on the glossaries package and usage [here](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/makeglossaries.html).

The [pagestyle](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/pagestyle.html) and [linespacing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Spacing) are not controlled by the glossaries, that is dependent on what you have those set to separately.